# Sharre Social Media Plugin Style Issue

Tags: css

Im working on implementing this Social Medial Plugin called Sharre:
http://sharrre.com

For example 5:
http://sharrre.com/example5.html

I cant determine how to style these buttons or tracking boxes so that they will fit on my page.  I would like to reduce the width and height for both.

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/uhhwt/

For example, I have tried to modify the width of the .button which doesnt seem to work:

```
#example5{
float:left;
margin:28px 0 0 10px;
}

.sharrre .button{
float:left;
width:60px;
}
```

I have also seen in the docs that:

```
twitter: {  //http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton
url: '',  //if you need to personalize url button
```

Does this imply that I would need to modify the size of the Image?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you can't. These plugins are provided by the networks, so if they make it so they can only be one size, there's not alot you can do.

Comment: @ACarter I red something about personalizing the button in the docs, added to my question.

Comment: I don't know. The best way would be too look at each of the network's pages about the buttons, and see how they say you can customize them. You may have to don it manually without the plugin then, though.

Comment: @ACarter do you know of a CSS trick where I could just hide those counter boxes?

Comment: Not really. They're in totally different html documents (but are within a common one) in iFrames, and you can't edit the contents of iFrames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin utilizes `<iframe>` elements and `background-image` to display the icons. You won't be able to modify them without cutting off part of the images. If you need to change the size of the icon, I would recommend resizing it via your favorite graphics program, uploading it to your server, and calling it via the custom parameter `url` that you mentioned.

Comment: do you see any way to just do away with the counter boxes?

Comment: Not with this particular plugin, unfortunately. You may want to try [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/).

Comment: yea your right, I've used ShareThis before, and it seems a bit more straight-forward.